# using DataBinder.Eval inside validation

Tags: asp.net, validation, user-controls

I am creating a multi-language site with umbraco and I would like to use dictionary items with my validation error messages.

I put the following code in the ErrorMessage field but it doesn't seem to work

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="NameRequiredFieldValidator" runat="server" 
  ErrorMessage='<%#(string)DataBinder.Eval(Container, library.GetDictionaryItem("NameValid")) %>'
    ControlToValidate="NameTextBox" ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="ContactUs" 
      Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

is there a way to do this?

Comment: what is happening when u put ur code...i mean it gives any error

Comment: is it inside a `gridview` or something?

Comment: I am not getting an error, I am supposed to get a string back, but I can't see it anywhere.

the field isn't inside a grid view

Comment: anybody can help with this?